# Finding a name in a txt file using the first letter

Tags: python, file, attributeerror, txt

I have a txt file with a list of country names and a couple of other things, for example:

```
Afghanistan,Asia,31.8,251772
Albania,Europe,3.0,11100
```

I need to have the user input a letter and then have all the countries with that letter be printed, for example

```
Enter a letter: A
Aganistan 
Albania
etc
```

I have this so far

```
def find_country_by_letter(letter):
   
#opening file
    file = open("un.txt", "r")

#reading the file 
    lines = file.readline() 
    
#spliting the list into countries names
    split = lines.split(",")

#empty list for countries
    names = ()
    
    for line in split:
        
        if line.startwith(letter):
            names.append()
 
     
    print(names)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    find_country_by_letter(print(input("Enter a Letter: ")))
```

but it gives me the error

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'startwith'
```

and I cant figure out another way to do it or how to fix it

Comment: You misspelled the function name.  It's `startswith`, not `startwith`.  You left out the `s` in the middle.

Comment: A separate issues is arguments are evaluated before function calls, thus the print in `print(input("Enter a Letter: "))` causes None to be passed to function find_country_by_letter.

Comment: `names = ()` makes an immutable tuple, not a mutable list. Use `names = []`.  `names.append()` isn't appending anything.  `lines.readline()` reads only one line.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few mistakes in your code, misspelling of the **startswith()** function, wrong way of inserting the input as parameter. Should be just:

```
find_country_by_letter(input("Enter a letter: "))
```

because the input function in itself takes as value whatever the user will input.

For your purpose, I would suggest using regex, it will be faster and better.

Here is an example:

```
import re


def find_country_by_letter(letter):
    with open('errors') as f:
        text = f.read()
                                    
    found_countries = re.findall(f'(?<!\w){letter.upper()}\w*', text)
    for country in found_countries:
        print(country)
    if not found_countries:
        print('No countries found starting with that letter!')
    return found_countries
```